# Resize Partitions in OpenBSD

Tags: unix, bsd, openbsd

I'm currently trying to install OpenBSD with gnome. I'm having the issue that my /dev/wd0h (/usr/local) disk partition is full, while some of the other have 1 or 2 GB free.
I'm trying to resize the partitions, to move some of the available space from other partitions to /dev/wd0h.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: During the installation it seems nearly impossible to edit partitions sizes: after some manual edits of sizes of partitions, then all the partitions become the same as autoinstall

Answer (score 3):

If you have spare unallocated space it is possible:
[Growing disk partitions from the OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#GrowPartition)